# Biblatex - customizing the authoryear style?

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

I am using Biblatex and I need a certain author-year style.

So I was thinking about customizing the existing authoryear style in Biblatex.

Bibliographical references should look like this:

> (Levy, 2015) or (Jenne, 2021, p. 323) or (Verbeek and Zaslove, 2017)

The bibliography should look like this:

**Journal article:**

> Jenne, E. K. (2021) 'Populism, nationalism and revisionist foreign policy'. *International Affairs*, Vol. 91, No. 2, pp. 323–344.

**Book:**

> Levy, Y. B.-H. (2015) *The Undiplomats: Right-wing populists and their foreign policies* (Brussels: Centre for European Reforms).

**Chapter in Book:**

> Verbeek, B. and Zaslove, A. (2017). 'Populism and Foreign Policy.' In Kaltwasser, C. R. et al. (eds.) *The Oxford Handbook of Populism* (Oxford: Oxford University Press), pp. 489–514.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}

@article{Jenne2021,
    author = {Jenne, Erin K.},
    date-added = {2021-03-12 10:30:48 +0100},
    date-modified = {2021-03-12 10:31:33 +0100},
    doi = {10.1093/ia/iiaa230},
    journal = {International Affairs},
    number = {2},
    pages = {323-344},
    title = {Populism, nationalism and revisionist foreign policy},
    volume = {91},
    year = {2021}}


@book{Levy2015,
    address = {Brussels},
    author = {Levy, Yehuda Ben-Hur},
    date-added = {2020-12-04 11:27:23 +0100},
    date-modified = {2021-03-11 10:13:56 +0100},
    publisher = {Centre for European Reforms},
    shorttitle = {The Undiplomats},
    title = {The Undiplomats: Right-wing populists and their foreign policies},
    year = {2015}}


@incollection{Verbeek2017,
    address = {Oxford},
    author = {Verbeek, Bertjan and Zaslove, Andrej},
    booktitle = {The Oxford Handbook of Populism},
    date-added = {2020-12-15 12:21:34 +0100},
    date-modified = {2020-12-15 12:24:41 +0100},
    editor = {Rovira Kaltwasser, Crist{\'o}bal and Taggart, Paul and Ochoa Espejo, Paulina and Ostiguy, Pierre},
    pages = {489-514},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    title = {Populism and Foreign Policy},
    year = {2017}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% package for switching quotation marks
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

% giveinits --> print only initiatls of first(given) name
\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% add vol. and no. to citation
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% was: \setunit*{\addspace}
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}}% was: \setunit{\addspace}
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}
%%%

\begin{document}
Journal article \autocite[323]{Jenne2021}.

Book \autocite{Levy2015}

Chapter in Bool\autocite{Verbeek2017}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the output is similar, but not exactly what I want.

**Journal article:**

> Jenne, E. K. (2021). ‘Populism, nationalism and revisionist foreign policy’. In: International Affairs, vol. 91, no. 2, pp. 323–344. doi: 10.1093/ia/iiaa230.

- "vol." and "no." with no capital letters at beginning
- punctuation after year
- "In:" before journal name

**Book:**

> Levy, Y. B.-H. (2015). The Undiplomats: Right-wing populists and their foreign policies. Brussels: Centre for European Reforms.

- punctuation after year
- punctuation after title
- address and publisher not in brackets

**Chapter in Book:**

> Verbeek, B. and A. Zaslove (2017). ‘Populism and Foreign Policy’. In: *The Oxford Handbook of Populism*. Ed. by C. Rovira Kaltwasser et al. Oxford: Oxford University Press, pp. 489–514.

- punctuation after year
- second author beginning with first name
- quotation mark in title before punctuation
- "In:" instead of "In"
- title of book before editors instead after
- editors beginning with first name instead of last name
- no (eds.) after editors
- address and publisher not in brackets

Does anyone know a better citation style that matches my requirements? Or can anyone please help me to further customize this style?

I am really looking forward to your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With a style from the [`biblate-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author</sup> as basis, most things can be taken care of either with options or other customisation settings of the style.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  articlein=false,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibcpstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibcpstring{number}\addnbspace #1}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
       not test {\iflistundef{location}}
    or not test {\iflistundef{#1}}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printlist{location}%
       \iflistundef{#1}
         {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
         {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
       \printlist{#1}%
       \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
       \usebibmacro{date}%
       \newunit}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jenne2021,
  author  = {Jenne, Erin K.},
  doi     = {10.1093/ia/iiaa230},
  journal = {International Affairs},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {323-344},
  title   = {Populism, nationalism and revisionist foreign policy},
  volume  = {91},
  year    = {2021},
}
@book{Levy2015,
  address    = {Brussels},
  author     = {Levy, Yehuda Ben-Hur},
  publisher  = {Centre for European Reforms},
  title      = {The Undiplomats},
  subtitle   = {Right-wing populists and their foreign policies},
  year       = {2015},
}
@incollection{Verbeek2017,
  address   = {Oxford},
  author    = {Verbeek, Bertjan and Zaslove, Andrej},
  booktitle = {The Oxford Handbook of Populism},
  address   = {Oxford},
  editor    = {Rovira Kaltwasser, Cristóbal and Taggart, Paul
               and Ochoa Espejo, Paulina and Ostiguy, Pierre},
  pages     = {489-514},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  title     = {Populism and Foreign Policy},
  year      = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Journal article \autocite[323]{Jenne2021}.

Book \autocite{Levy2015}

Chapter in Bool \autocite{Verbeek2017}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jenne, E. K. (2021) ‘Populism, nationalism and revisionist foreign policy’. International Afairs, Vol. 91, No. 2, pp. 323–344. https://doi.org/10.1093/ia/iiaa230.//Levy, Y. B.-H. (2015) The Undiplomats. Right-wing populists and their foreign policies (Brussels: Centre for European Reforms).//Verbeek, B. and A. Zaslove (2017) ‘Populism and Foreign Policy’. In Rovira Kaltwasser, C. et al. (eds.) The Oxford Handbook of Populism (Oxford: Oxford University Press), pp. 489–514.]

Most commands used here should have fairly self-explanatory names. The `biblatex-ext` settings are documented in [the `biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

Comment: Great, thank you! But is there also a way to get rid of "DOI" and just print the url of the DOI?

Comment: @feder80 Have a look at the edit.